# Cross Validation K-Fold with Forecast Package in R

Tags: r, fft, forecasting, cross-validation, arima

I have created a model in R using the `forecast` package.

My source of learning this is from here: 
https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/dailydata/

I am using the last section which includes fourier series as such:

```
y <- ts(x, frequency=7)
z <- fourier(ts(x, frequency=365.25), K=5)
zf <- fourier(ts(x, frequency=365.25), K=5, h=100)
fit <- auto.arima(y, xreg=cbind(z,holiday), seasonal=FALSE)
fc <- forecast(fit, xreg=cbind(zf,holidayf), h=100)
```

After I create this model, is there a way I can do a cross validation k-fold test to determine the error and adjusted error?

I know how to do it with a generalized linear model as such:

```
library(boot)
lm1 <- glm(ValuePerSqFt ~ Units + SqFt + Boro, data = housing)
lm1cv <- cv.glm(housing, lm1, K=5)
lm1cv$delta
[1] 1870.31 1869.352
```

This shows the error and adjusted error.

Is there a function in the forecast package that can do this and it will help me compare the accuracy of this model with the glm model?

Comment: Standard CV makes little sense with time series models as you can only forecast the future based on the past. There are exceptions (see https://robjhyndman.com/publications/cv-time-series/), but this does not include dynamic regression models.

Comment: @RobHyndman do you recommend I just use the accuracy function and compare errors on predictions?

Comment: standard cross-validation is pointless but I suspect @RobHyndman meant [time series cross validation](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/tscv/), is it possible for ts regression  models?

Comment: I meant what I wrote. Read the link.

Comment: How did you determine the value of K for your Fourier?

Comment: Answer is in this question here @RiteshSinha https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53198334/understanding-fourier-for-seasonality

Comment: This looks perfect !!

Comment: @RiteshSinha glad it helped!